Reproducing strong visual effect of the rotating cube illusion
A very "strong" visual effect illusion was posted recently HERE. Here a few frames of it at low resolution. The cubes are NOT rotating in reality. Curious: to see cube NOT moving use "cross-eyed viewing" as you would do for a stereogram and a static cube will appear in the middle.

Notice, cubes rotate in different directions. If you look at it at high resolution screenshot (click to zoom on the image below) you will see the difference at the edges of cube frames - different colors, different sides - that's probably the source of the illusion:

Here is a starter code to implement a cube with rotating background. Define half-disk:
halfDisk[angle_:0,color_:Black,radius_:.5,center_:{.5,.5}]:=
{color,DiskSegment[center,radius,{angle+0,angle+Pi}]}

The rest is pretty easy. The control of Manipulate is the angle of rotation:
Manipulate[Graphics3D[
{EdgeForm[Directive[Thickness[.03],Orange]],FaceForm[None],Cube[]},
Prolog->{halfDisk[-a],halfDisk[Pi-a,White]},
ViewPoint->5.{Sin[2],Cos[2],.4},
Boxed->False,SphericalRegion->True,Background->Gray]
,{a,0,2Pi}]

You can generate a .GIF or .MP4 by replacing Manipulate with a Table and using Export to the corresponding file format. Or use any other method, the above code is not necessarily the best idea to start from, up to you.
Obviously this minimal rotation is not enough to create the visual effect. Probably something close to things discussed here is happening:

Visual motion illusions
More about visual motion illusions
Optical illusion of motion based on change of colors

I am looking for any (but desirably minimal and clear) implementation that reproduces this strong visual effect.

Why do you need a minimal implementation?

My first thought was in terms of Graphics, not Graphics3D. Does it matter to you?

@MichaelE2 absolutely, could be simply Image too. Any way that hits the goal works for me.

@DavidG.Stork David, I think you are right, I updated the title.

What is the point of rotating background? Because same illusion can be done with static background. https://imgur.com/these-cubes-arent-moving-UNg4WVB Maybe it was just a first try on that illusion and later it was found that rotating background is not necessary? Otherwise I see no advantage in having rotating background.

Now I noticed the difference between the two. In OP question the orange color of cube is static and  the background is blinking black and white (by rotating half disk) while in the link I provided it is the opposite. Background is static but the color of the cube is blinking black and white.

Here's a youtube video of a guy analyzing it.  Youtube let's you slow down the frame rate to 1/4 so you can see what's happening.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lW27YO6lCD8

How about this?
Clear["Global`*"];
frame3D = Module[{edgelen = 50, vcs, a, b, c, d, e},
   vcs = edgelen*PolyhedronData["Cube", "VertexCoordinates"];
   {EdgeForm[None], 
    Table[{a, b} = vcs[[edge]]; {a, b, {c, d} = NullSpace[{a - b}]}; 
     e = Rescale[b - a]; Cuboid[a - c - d - e, b + c + d + e],
     {edge, PolyhedronData["Cube", "EdgeIndices"]}]}
   ];
viewpoint = {0.95, -3.1, 1.3};
angularvelocity = 0.01;
{frame1, frame2} = 
  Table[Binarize@
    Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[None], Glow[White], 
      Rotate[frame3D, th, {0, 0, 1}]}, Boxed -> False, 
     Lighting -> None, SphericalRegion -> True, Background -> Black, 
     ViewPoint -> viewpoint, ImageMargins -> 20, 
     ImageSize -> 160], {th, angularvelocity*{0, 1}}];
nframe = 24;
halfdisks[pos_, th_] := {White, EdgeForm[None], Disk[pos, 1.8], Black,
    Disk[pos, 1.8, {th, th + Pi}]};
sideshift = 0.01;
delta = Pi/2;
bg[th_] := Image@Graphics[{
     halfdisks[{-2 - sideshift, 0}, th + delta],
     halfdisks[{-2, 0}, th],
     halfdisks[{2 + sideshift, 0}, th + delta],
     halfdisks[{2, 0}, th]},
    PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-2, 2}}, ImageSize -> 400, 
    Background -> GrayLevel[.5]];
m1 = ImageAssemble[{{frame2, frame1}}];
m2 = ImageAssemble[{{frame1, frame2}}];
orange = {1., .5, 0.};
imagelist = ParallelTable[
   GaussianFilter[
    Image[Transpose[
       ImageData /@ {m1, m2, bg[th], bg[th - delta]}, {3, 1, 2}] /. {
       {0, 0, x_, y_} :> x,
       {0, 1, x_, y_} :> y,
       {1, 0, x_, y_} :> x,
       {1, 1, x_, y_} :> orange}], 2]
   , {th, -3*2. Pi*Most[Subdivide[nframe]]}];
ListAnimate[imagelist, nframe]


Note:
I first browsed the web pages cited in the question; they are very suggestive. I learned that our visions are very sensitive to the change of the image of the object of interest.
Probably this is the instinctual abilities acquired through the process of evolution, and also reflects the physical fact that every motion is continuous. Therefore, hints to the visual effect of motion illusions would be hidden near the boundary or edges of the "moving" objects.
I first noticed that the rotating black-and-white disks look moving away slowly. What makes this visual effect? The following is a (somwhat exaggerated) example of image frame.

This is made from two different images (A) and (B) of BW disks. (A) is the image of the disks at time $t$. (B) is the image of the disks under illusionary motion at slightly later time $t+\Delta t$. The  above is obtained by overlaying (A) on top of (B).
As a result, we have thin areas along the farther side of boundaries of the disks, black on the left and white on the right. Of course, they arise from the difference between (B) and (A).
Our visual attention is directed to this portion of the image, because information about what will happen next is concentrated to this area. I hypothesized that this continual attention to some particular side of the object is the key mechanism of the illusionary motion.
If we accept this hypothesis, what we should do to rotate the cubes is now clear. We have to "emphasize" the difference of images of the cubes at time $t$ and $t+\Delta t$.
The images of rotating cubes can be obtained
by 3D data of cube (frame3D in the code) and Rotate[]. The variables frame1 and frame2 contain the binary images at $t$ and $t+\Delta t$, respectively.
Contrary to the moving disk case, we need to figure out how to emphasize the difference of frame1 and frame2 put on a background image which is also changing. I spend some time to find a way to realize this effect. The simplest answer I got is: Use the opposite color to the background. For example,

The code is a little difficult to understand, but I hope this note
helps you.

(+1) Yes, this the the key to draw such animation.

(+1) This is nice attempt.

(+1) Awesome ! Love this. Thank you.

Kato - could you explain a bit on words what makes illusion happen. Also why do you think it got a bit different feel than the original? Appreciated.

@cvgmt what exactly did you mean by "the the key to draw such animation" ?

@VitaliyKaurov There are several black and white serif in the frame of the cube.

Thank you for accepting my answer. I added a note to the answer. Yes, the key is the serif in the frame as pointed out by @cvgmt.

I spent most of the time to just reproduce the visual effect. I did not tried to make the image looks as close as possible. To reduce deviation from the original, you can adjust the parameters such as nframes, angularvelocity, sideshift, edgelen, orange (color of the cube), etc.

If the logic of changing of contour colors is not identified than there is a little chance to reproduce the original illusion effect correctly. Nice attempt but compared to the original animation it is evident that the correct logic was not found.

Maybe someone can improve this animation. Here you need to play with the rotation speed of disk and the rotation speed of the light source.
halfDisk[angle_ : 0, color_ : Black, radius_ : .5, 
  center_ : {.5, .5}] := {color, 
  DiskSegment[center, radius, {angle + 0, angle + Pi}]}; 
tube[r_, t_, t1_] := 
 Graphics3D[{White, 
   Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0,
       1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}, r], 
   Tube[{{1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}}, r], Tube[{{1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}, r], 
   Tube[{{0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}}, r]}, Boxed -> False, 
  Prolog -> {halfDisk[-t], halfDisk[Pi - t, White]}, 
  ImageSize -> Tiny, Background -> Gray, SphericalRegion -> True, 
  ViewAngle -> Pi/10, ViewPoint -> 5. {Sin[1], Cos[1], .4}, 
  PlotRange -> All, 
  Lighting -> PointLight[White, 35 {Cos[t1], Sin[t1], 0.}]];

frames = 
  Table[GraphicsRow[{tube[.025, 2  t, -2 t], 
     tube[.025, 2 t, 2 t]}], {t, 0, 2  Pi, Pi/11}];

pp = ListAnimate[frames, 23]



(+1)  Some days ago,I want to draw the 2D render graphics of the frame of the cube, but not so successful.

(+1) Very interesting. Even though no rotation motion effect is there and pretty powerful. Thank you.

@VitaliyKaurov Unfortunately, I have one eye that doesn't work, so I can't see how the "cross-eyed viewing" is achieved. What can be seen in this case?

@AlexTrounev It is not meant to look at it by "cross-eyed viewing". The original illusion can be seen even with only one eye.

@azerbajdzan Sorry, my question is about picture in my post. How it looks like with "cross-eyed viewing"?

@AlexTrounev the original looks not-rotating. Yours look not moving. The opposite directions of motion seem to compensate each other in the brain and the centered overlapping image is motionless.

@VitaliyKaurov Thank you. It's like a stroboscopic effect. Here, a cylindrical surface acts as a light modulator.
